# How does Pandas calculate quantiles?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following simple dataframe:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'calc_value': [0, 0.081928, 0.94444]})
> df
   calc_value
0    0.000000
1    0.081928
2    0.944440
```

Why does [`df.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) calculate the 90th percentile as `0.7719376`?

```
> df.quantile(0.9)['calc_value']`
0.7719376
```

According to my calculations it should be `0.69`, via `(0.944444-0.081928)*((90-50)/(100-50))`.

Comment: there are lots of different ways to compute quantiles: http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.mquantiles.html (personally, I'm a weibull kind of guy)

Comment: also looks like `pandas.core.frame._quantile` uses `numpy.percentile` under the hood: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, step per 0.1 in the range from 0.5...1.0 is equal to (0.94444-0.081928)/5 and is equal to 0.1725024

```
So 50q is 0.081928
60q is 0.081928+0.1725024=0.25443
70q is 0.081928+2*0.1725024=0.426933
80q is 0.081928+3*0.1725024=0.599435
90q is 0.081928+4*0.1725024=0.771938
100q is 0.081928+5*0.1725024=0.94444
```

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I forgot to add `0.081928` afterwards.